# How do I get local parent branch commit update

Tags: git

I have a local branch A branched from master, and branch B branched from A, if I have amend the commit in branch A. How can I get the branch A update in Branch B.

Comment: Amending a commit that is a parent of other commits is probably not a good idea. Instead, you should add a new commit to branch A, and then merge from A to B.

Comment: @NamshubWriter I do not totally agree because it will end with a more convoluted history that is not always a good thing...

Answer (score 1):

You can update the B branch after the amend by [rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) it.

Initially, you may have something like this:

```
* 9a808df (HEAD, B) Initial B branch commit
* 2d6684f (A) Initial A branch commit
* 88fe061 (master) added some changes
* 90499d4 initial commit
```

If you `checkout` to branch A, `add` some changes, then `commit --amend`, you'll have the following:

```
* 0f99377 (HEAD, A) Initial A branch commit with some amended changes
| * 9a808df (B) Initial B branch commit
| * 2d6684f Initial A branch commit
|/  
* 88fe061 (master) added some changes
* 90499d4 initial commit
```

As you can see, branch B preserves the original A commit in its history, while branch A now has a different version of this commit.

**Solution**: What you want is *update B's base to that new commit*, i.e.

```
git branch new_base 0f99377
git checkout B
git rebase new_base
git branch -d new_base
```

An then, at the end you'll have the following:

```
* 57db150 (HEAD, B) Initial B branch commit
* 0f99377 (A) Initial A branch commit with some amended changes
* 88fe061 (master) added some changes
* 90499d4 initial commit
```

Comment: With your solution, you can't guarantee that the rebase do not end up in a merge conflict (depending on the changes done), so doing a `rebase --onto` is a better idea...

Comment: Are you sure? Can you elaborate your answer a little more? I think it is an interesting question :)

Comment: If you amend the commit to add new changes, the rebase will work without conflicts. But if modify a change introduced in the commit (update a line already modified in this commit), your rebase will not apply without a conflict. But in this case, you could also skip applying the commit if you end up with a conflict when applying the **first** commit.

Comment: Guys Thanks for the answer, I think one thing I found useful is use interactive rebase. When you rebase A, git created new commit of A, by doing git rebase -i A, you are able to delete the new commit so you don't carry that over.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution consists in using [git rebase --onto](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) and selecting the good commits...